# In the figure shown below, why the current through 10 ohm resistor is zero?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

This is a practice question from the book circuit theory by A. Chakrabarti. I didn't understand how  current through the branch C-D is zero.

Why is the current not zero?

Comment: Current has to flow in a loop...until you get to things like antennas and transmission lines, but you won't have to worry about that for a loooonnnnggg while (if you ever even have to).

Answer (score 3):

No current can flow from C to D, a current must have a loop to flow back to the source.

If you connected c to e or b to d then current could flow, otherwise the current is zero.

The first thing to check is to see if there is a current loop if there is a voltage or current source.